# Camera preview size issue

Tags: android, camera

I am developing a custom camera app and I am facing the problem with setting the preview size for the camera. The problem is that the camera preview does not persist the aspect ration so the preview looks stretched to the sides.

The code I use to calculate the best size:

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {


        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 1;
        double targetRatio=(double)w / h; 

        if (sizes == null){
            return null;
        }

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {

            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            Log.d("Test", "Ration: " + Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio));
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
                continue;
            }

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {

            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    Log.d("Test", "MATCFH!");
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }



        return optimalSize;
    }
```

I have been struggling with this for a day now and cannot find an optimal solution. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, changing camera preview size may not preserve aspect ratio. To keep the preview display look nice, you should resize the preview surfaceView accordingly.

Comment: So there is not way how to keep the surfaceView in full screen mode with preserving the aspect ratio?? What about native camera app, that works in full screen with proper aspect ratio?? Does it use some calculations based on distance etc??

Comment: The system camera app leaves black margins for 4x3 resolutions, but it is carefully designed to look nice in both 16x9 (a.k.a. wide) and 4x3 formats.